# In Maria DB i can use CASE with table?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, case

I need to select in a stored procedure between two table with a CASE condition .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRO (...., TypeA TINYTEXT)
BEGIN
....
INSERT INTO
CASE TypeA
WHEN ValueA THEN `database`.`TableA`
WHEN ValueB THEN `database`.`TableB`
END
(`ColumnA`, `ColumnB`, `ColumnC`) VALUES (....);
END
...

...
END;
```

but it tell me that there is a syntax error in this case.
Where i Wrong?

Comment: It is invalid syntax; dynamic table determination is not allowed in any query; not INSERT, not SELECT, and not UPDATE. You can dynamically construct a query string that can be PREPAREd and EXECUTEd; but that is not much different than constructing one in a similar manner client side.

Comment: You need a dynamic SQL in that case and variables.

Comment: Also, if you're inserting in different tables there is usually a non-trivial difference in data structure, making the need for syntax for what you are trying to do mostly non-existent. Since the fields are apparently the same, why are there two different tables with identical structure? Perhaps the two tables should be merged with a new `TypeA` field added.

Answer (score 2):

The [`CASE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) cannot be used to choose in wich table you want to `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`, or `SELECT`).

A solution would be to move the `CASE` outside of the query, like:

```
CASE TypeA
    WHEN 'ValueA' THEN INSERT INTO `database`.`TableA` (`ColumnA`, `ColumnB`, `ColumnC`) VALUES (....);
    WHEN 'ValueB' THEN INSERT INTO `database`.`TableB` (`ColumnA`, `ColumnB`, `ColumnC`) VALUES (....);
END CASE
```

This could also be done with the [`IF` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html).

Another option would be to use dynamic SQL, but I believe that would be more complicated than the above option.

Comment: Perfect it funtions